# Applying conditional statement to time column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a python code that converts one column df[r_t] to utc:

```
   df.r_t = pd.to_datetime(df.r_t)
```

And generate another column for time:

```
    df['time'] = (df['r_t'].dt.time)
```

My resulting column is as follows:

```
|         r_t             |   time    |
| ----------------------- | --------- |
| 2022-05-28 00:00:00+00  | 00:00:00  |
| 2022-05-28 00:00:01+00  | 00:00:01  |
| 2022-05-28 00:00:02+00  | 00:00:02  |
```

We have 20k rows.
Now what am trying to do is generate a night and day dataframe: Like

```
   time_1 = pd.to_datetime('04:00:00')
   time_2 = pd.to_datetime('09:00:00')
   df_day = df[(df['time'] > time_1) & (df['time'] <= time_2)]
   df_night = not in(df[(df['time'] > time_1) & (df['time'] <= time_2)])
```

I know am doing this wrong as i get error:

```
    TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'Timestamp'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
time_day = pd.to_datetime("04:00:00").time()
time_night = pd.to_datetime("09:00:00").time()

mask = (df["time"] > time_day) & (df["time"] <= time_night)

df_day = df[mask]
df_night = df[~mask]
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted. I appreciate your speedy response.